# Adding an UIImageView into the Subview

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I have a function which is meant to be adding things into the Subview.

```
    func addView(object: UIImageView){
        view.addSubview(object)
    }
```

In another class I got a function, that want to use the add function.

```
    var field = UIImage(named: "Picture.png")
    var field1 = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(fieldX, fieldY, fieldWidht, feldLength))
    field1.image = field
    addView(field1)
```

The problem I have is saying:

> Use of unsolve identifier 'addView'

in the same line where I try to get the access on this function: `(addView(field1))`.

Comment: what's the problem that you are having

Comment: Thank you i added the post.

Comment: what is `field1` ? and is the `addView` method in the same class where you are trying to use it

Comment: No the addView method and the other code where I try to get the access on, are in two different classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are calling this function from another class, you need to create an instance of that class, let's say the `addView` function was into a class called `MainClassViewController`

```
let targetController = MainClassViewController()
```

Then in your code where you want to call that function you do the following:

```
 let field = UIImage(named: "Picture.png")
 let field1 = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(fieldX, fieldY, fieldWidht, feldLength))
 field1.image = field
 targetController.addView(field1)  //<-- this is how you call that function
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the first class instance. You need first to init the class, and then you can call the `addView:` function.